# Understanding and implementation of gRPC asynchronous operation in Go lang

Tags: asynchronous, go, grpc

I am still suffering from this problem: 
I know that with Go lang we can implement high-performance network service easily. I picked gRPC protocol and I had better implement asynchronous operation because it is more powerful than synchronous:

- Can you tell me more details about the benefits of using asynchronous operation over the synchronous operation?
- Can you guide me how to implement Go lang or Python asynchronous services, or give me its sample code, I have read this article https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/async/helloasync-cpp.html but those kinds of code are beyond my knowledge

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important for you to do some more research and study, and clear up some of these concepts you're dealing with.

In terms of sync and async services, I did a little Googling and randomly selected [this](https://docs.apigee.com/api-baas/get-started/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-calls) page which seems to give a good definition of the terms:

> If an API call is synchronous, it means that code execution will block (or wait) for the API call to return before continuing.
>
> Asynchronous calls do not block (or wait) for the API call to return from the server. Execution continues on in your program, and when the call returns from the server, a "callback" function is executed.

Your statement that "asynchronous operation is more powerful than synchronous" seems misguided.  They each have different applications that are appropriate in different scenarios.  If you have a specific scenario you care about, that would help narrow down the question.

Here is the [definition of gRPC](https://grpc.io/about/):

> gRPC is a modern open source high performance RPC framework that can run in any environment.

The key point here is RPC, or "Remote Procedure Call".  In gRPC a call is synchronous, even if it is streaming: the connection is opened, the request is sent/streamed, the response is sent/streamed, and the connection is closed.  Developing an "asynchronous service" implies a second call in the reverse direction, something which is not covered in the sphere of gRPC itself.  I guess you could use gRPC to do this sort of thing but I don't think that is normal.

Otherwise I would suggest you read the [gRPC Basics](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/go.html) guide, and there is [sample code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/route_guide) as well.  It is available in Python as well if you check the gRPC site.

Comment: Thanks, Matt Mc!
Actually, your answer clarified many questions of mine, I am discovering the given documentation from your post.